# run command, specify N docker containers instances across swarm cluster

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I have 4 swarm nodes. I want to run 4 instances of a container in one command, is this possible w/ swarm? I.E. something like

```
docker -H tcp://swarmgr:port run --instances 4 imagename .....etc
```

Comment: Use docker-compose instead.